# I See colors in the highlight of my video and images. Sony a7iv

Tags: sony, camera

I See colors in the highlight of my video and images. Sony a7iv

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be longitudinal chromatic aberrations (LoCA). Notice that it goes from magenta (red) to cyan (blue) at longer distances; behind the faucet in the both pictures. That's because red (long) and blue (short) wavelengths focus at different distances than green (medium) does when uncorrected.

A better corrected lens, and/or stopping down to a smaller aperture are the solutions. Many editors have automatic CA removal functions, but all they really do is change/remove the color of it.